# How to call restful services in android

Tags: android, rest

I'm porting some of my Windows Phone 7 apps to Android.  When we call services in the WP7 world, the calls are async.  We call the service and there is a delegate _completed event that triggers when when the result is returned.  Meanwhile we go on about our way.

The java android code pasted below is how I am calling an HTTP service on my cloud server.  I developed this code by going through Android tutorials teaching how to call a service in the android world.  Apparently, service calls here are synchronus so the instruction starting with InputStream in... doesn't get executed until the result is returned.

Is this how it is supposed to work for Android?  If the service does not respond, there is a wait of a couple minutes and then a timeout exception takes place.  That's no good.  Everything will hang.

What is the reccommended way to call services in android?
Thanks, Gary

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.deanblakely.com/REST/api/products");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());     
            String myString = readStream(in);
            String otherString = myString;
            otherString = otherString + " ";
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        finally 
        {     
            urlConnection.disconnect();   
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this how it is supposed to work for Android?

Yes. Do HTTP operations in a background thread, such as the one supplied by an `AsyncTask`.

> If the service does not respond, there is a wait of a couple minutes and then a timeout exception takes place. That's no good. Everything will hang.

You can set a socket timeout to be something shorter than "a couple minutes". For example, you can call `setReadTimeout()` on your `HttpURLConnection` to specify a timeout period in milliseconds.

Comment: I'm aware of your chapter on "Dealing with Threads."  I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't something specially built into the API for service calls that I wasn't aware of (like there is in C#).  Thanks.

Comment: @user1058647: Not specifically for networking. Generally speaking, Android has not changed networking very much, leveraging existing Java stuff for it, most of which has taken the block-a-background-thread approach. There are other facets of the Android API that employ the async-operation-with-listener pattern (e.g., `MediaPlayer`). And there may be third-party libraries that give you the async-operation-with-listener pattern for Java networking that you could use on Android, though I cannot recall any off the top of my head.

Comment: Never use AsynTask to perform network request or whatever that need to be persisted. Async Task are strongly tied to your activity and if the user change the orientation of the screen since the App is re created the AsyncTask will be stopped.

I suggest you to use Service pattern with Intent Service and ResultReceiver. Take a look to [RESTDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid). It's a library that allows you to perform any kind of REST request asynchronously and notify your UI with Request Listeners implementing the Virgil Dobjanschi's service pattern.

Comment: @Pcriulan: "if the user change the orientation of the screen since the App is re created the AsyncTask will be stopped" -- no, it will not. There is no question that `AsyncTask` needs to be managed as part of the configuration change process, but done properly (e.g., retained fragments), it works just fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes you're right, I just wanted to notice that the AsyncTask will try to update the UI of the old activity, not the new created after rotating your device

Comment: @Pcriulan: Again, that's not necessarily the case. A poorly-written `AsyncTask` may have that "feature", but not a well-written one.